# Replacing mysql_real_escape_string in WordPress theme

Tags: php, themes

I'm having an issue with **mysql_real_escape_string**. This is used to display a custom post type (food menu items) for the WooThemes Diner theme. Food menu items no longer display on the Diner menu page because they are being called with **mysql_real_escape_string**.

What is the proper way to call these items?

Theme: [Diner by WooThemes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/diner/) version 1.9.8 (now retired from active support)

Affected file: admin-interface.php

Lines: 111 & 118

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* WooThemes Admin Interface - woothemes_add_admin */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_add_admin' ) ) {
function woothemes_add_admin() {

    global $query_string;
    global $current_user;
    $current_user_id = $current_user->user_login;
    $super_user = get_option( 'framework_woo_super_user' );

    $themename =  get_option( 'woo_themename' );
    $shortname =  get_option( 'woo_shortname' );

    // Reset the settings, sanitizing the various requests made.
    // Use a SWITCH to determine which settings to update.

    /* Make sure we're making a request.
------------------------------------------------------------*/

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ) {

        // Sanitize page being requested.
        $_page = '';

        $_page = mysql_real_escape_string( strtolower( trim( strip_tags( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ) ) );

        // Sanitize action being requested.
        $_action = '';

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['woo_save'] ) ) {

            $_action = mysql_real_escape_string( strtolower( trim( strip_tags( $_REQUEST['woo_save'] ) ) ) );

        } // End IF Statement

        // If the action is "reset", run the SWITCH.

        /* Perform settings reset.
    ------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Sounds like your hosting environment recently upgraded to PHP7.  `mysql_real_escape_string` was deprecated previously but removed in PHP7.   It is possible that Woo has released an update for this theme.  Recommend contacting Woo for a fix.

Comment: Yes, I have already contacted Woo. They did issue a theme update but will not provide the file(s) to my client. My client could not locate the original receipt (they only found bank transactions) for the theme so Woo refused to provide the updated files.

Comment: downvoted as this is only part off the code which do not explain why there is escaping done at all. semms like this is just an horrible code and the escaping is just not needed., or at least not the escaping that was used

Answer (score 6):

As [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0, you can try [esc_sql()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql) to work for later WP/PHP versions.

Replace `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `esc_sql()` at line 111 & 118 in your `admin-interface.php` file.

Hope this should work well for you!

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, this didn't work. The menu items still do not show up when the menu page type is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` was deprecated previously and removed in PHP7. You have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. But I don't think it is possible with WordPress because you have pass the connection string also.

So alternately you can use [esc_sql()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql) instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
global $wpdb;
$string = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
$string = $wpdb->_real_escape($string);
```

link here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/